# Keychain username cant change

Tags: git, macos, github, keychain, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem with macOS keychain:

I'm using SourceTree app for GitHub projects.
when I push the project, everything is fine but SourceTree wants me to login with github account for push, so I logged in, but there is come error for username or password: I accidently type wrong username, but Apple already stored keychain for this.

I just go to keychain app delete the stored keychain for github then just opened the SourceTree, and still I'm getting the wrong username.
How can I delete the wrong username?

[image: Storedwrongusername]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to erase that keychain entry:

- from the Keychain GUI (as seen in "[Updating credentials from the macOS Keychain](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)")
- or in command line with:

  ```
   printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"|git credential-osxkeychain erase
  ```

Repeat the last command until it asks you for a username/password.

Check also your git remote -v (in the folder of your local repository) to ensure that the `origin` remote URL is:

- an HTTPS one (starting with `https://`)
- not including a username (`https://wrongUserName@github.com/...`)

The [OP seyfzone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16909470/seyfzone) adds that SourceTree itself has the account:

```
SourceTree > Preferences > Advanced > Delete Account
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found the other way 
SourceTree > Preferences > Advanced > Delete Account
it works, but now when I push the project trying to send for a long time (2 hour).
Project size 280 mb. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @seyfzone For testing, try an push a small repository to a GitHub testing repository, just to validate that the push can work.

Comment: No, doesn't work :(

Comment: @seyfzone Interesting: what did you change to make it work? (since you have accepted the answer)